# trying to generate list of all apps uploaded in android playstore

Tags: android, web-scraping, google-play, app-store

Problem- I want to make a list of all the apps listed in playstore.

context:

I am actually working on an app analytics algorithm and trying to backtest it using app data from google playstore.

The purpose of the study is to find any correlation between the length and other dynamics of an app name with its total downloads.

I understand it is easy to scrape/automate the part to find out the download range using selenium or other tools. However i am still trying to figure out a way to make a list of all apps in the playstore. From what i know, there are over 2 millions apps, and when i try to scroll any category of apps manually (clicking on 'see more' etc), i am able to see a few hundred after which the listings end.

**Grateful if anyone can suggest me how can i generate a list of all (or atleast a major chunk) apps listed on the playstore and appstore** using which then i will be able to scrape then scrape the corresponding download data to run my regression models. Need atleast a few hundred thousand data points for any meaningful model.

Thanking you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer, NO you can not get a list of all apps in Google Play.

but you can **scrape** a big chunk of them from mirror sites of Google Play, like for example: APKpure, and even then you should do this on stages, like **scraping** each category separately, because these sites are usually loading next pages of apps in the same page, and when this page gotten huge it will crash selenium for sure.